# Laravel/Eloquent/DB Query - Join when is null and not null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I'm trying this code without any success:

```
MyModel::join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'messages.from_country_id')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'messages.user_id')
         ->where('messages.id', '=', $id)
         ->select('users.name', 'messages.from_name', 'messages.from_email', 'messages.content', 'countries.code AS c_code', 'countries.name AS c_name')->firstOrFail();
```

But in some cases `messages.user_id` is null. What i want is to retrieve all messages, and each `message` with the correct `users.name`(when it's available).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking for a [left join](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries), which will get all messages, as well as the username for those that have it:

```
MyModel::join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'messages.from_country_id')
     ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'messages.user_id')
     ->where('messages.id', '=', $id)
     ->select('users.name', 'messages.from_name', 'messages.from_email', 'messages.content', 'countries.code AS c_code', 'countries.name AS c_name')->firstOrFail()
```

Comment: Best answer! Records will return even if messages are null. Thanks.